# Android C++ Native Code

Tags: c++, android, eclipse, mobile, native

I am a new Android developer and I would like to create an application using only C/C++ code for Android but I have found the documentation to be very limited. I can create an Android C/C++ project in eclipse, but it uses a lot of java code.

I'm using NativeActivity (new to 2.3) and I need help setting up my project. Does anyone know how to do this?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html

Comment: There are tutorials and docs for setting up a project. It needs to use Java to set up some native code, but that is as it should be. What is your exact problem? (i.e. Please ask a more specific question.)

Comment: I had the same problem. You can find the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190117/how-to-use-android-native-libraries-in-java-using-eclipse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove all of the generated Java code. You don't need it if you want a purely native activity. The only thing you need to do is to set up the Android Manifest file as shown in the documentation. In particular, you'll need:

```
        <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of or .so -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="native-activity" />
```

And you'll need to modify jni/Android.mk so that it builds a jni with the name lib_name.

Comment: You'll need to be using the latest NDK (r5) for this to work, by the way.

Comment: For for information on the native activity API, see: $(NDK_ROOT)/docs/NATIVE-ACTIVITY.HTML

Comment: I am looking at http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html .It also says "Compile the native code using the ndk-build command. " "cd <ndk-root>/samples/hello-jni" "<ndk_root>/ndk-build". However, when I try to do that I get "'C:\android\android-ndk-r5\ndk-build' is not recognized as an internal or external command".

I am trying to run "C:\android\android-ndk-r5\samples\hello-jni>C:\android\android-ndk-r5\ndk-build"

Answer (score 0):

Yuo can look into the [Lighthouse project](http://code.google.com/p/android-lighthouse/wiki/Compile) for android, which allows you to use Qt (and therefore C++) code instead of java. You still need 1 line of java code to kick off your Qt app.