# How to use android native libraries in Java using eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, shared-libraries, android-ndk

Can any body provide me a steps, How to use native libraries in eclipse. Your help highly appreciated. I don't want to create any native libraries. I just want to use predefined libraries.

Comment: To use native binaries in Android, we usually need to build wrapper native libraries with the NDK...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the [link](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/), which described how to use native libraries in your eclipse step by step. Very nice tutorial.

Comment: Is there another link?  Chrome warns me about malware for the one you include.

Comment: When i was accessed this link, it was working fine. Now it is having malware.  My system is now showing same message :(

Answer (score 1):

You could also avoid dealing with JNI and the NDK altogether by using JavaCPP:

http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/#Instructions_for_Android